# API's For converting A file into PDF

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I want  some API's and some Document So that i can convert any **file into PDF**..
The file may be `Doc , exl, ppt ..etc` .

My requirement is, i have a file EX:- Doc file and i just wants to convert it into PDF.. using java . 
Any suggestion will be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apache's poi` API is best for convert any file to `pdf`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you taking a look at [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) (former xhtmlrenderer) which makes creating PDF files extremely easy from XML and HTML files (internally it uses iText).

HTML/XML can be used as a intermediate format making this a quite flexible solution.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution if you want to generate a PDF from a HTML file. Flying Saucer uses iText to generate a PDF, without all the clutter yu can have with iText. Nice! http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html

Answer (score 2):

Use

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

and

http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a PDF from an XML document, you can try Apache FOP, which follows the XSL-FO standard.

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

So a smart process could be: extract data from your various document formats using POI, [odftoolkit](http://odftoolkit.org) (for OenDocument) or other tools, inject them into an XML container, and then translate them into PDF using FOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Itext](http://itextpdf.com/) . It is well documented and comes with ton of examples.